# Graphics in borland c++to add

Tags: c++, borland-c++, bgi

I am using borland c++ to run my c++ programs.How to add graphics library in it just as we have graphics.h in TURBO c++ ?? How to run my program with graphics command it it??

Comment: When you want to use turbo c++ libraries, you have to use turbo C++. Note that now, in the times of C++11, that is at the 3rd revision of the standard, a far pre-standard thing like turbo c++ is not considered being C++ by many people. Maybe it is time to step into the 21st century and get some up to date compiler, along with some up to date portable libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Windows GDI from Turbo C++. However, a better route to take would be to switch to using a modern implementation such as Visual Studio.

If it is just a personal project then Express Edition is freely available or you can purchase a Professional license from Microsoft. Alternatively there are other modern C++ implementations available such as g++.

Edit: Visual Studio Express Edition can be used commercially also.

Answer (score 0):

Borland CBuilder has VCL-Visual Component Library..you may use it by including it before #pragma hdrstop as vcl.h

Borland Help has lots of information about the components..